# Show that $(\Bbb Z/15\Bbb Z)^{\times}\simeq\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Show that $(\Bbb Z/15\Bbb Z)^{\times}\simeq\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$, where
$(\Bbb Z/15\Bbb Z)^{\times}$ is the group of integers modulo $15$ under multiplication.

This is a question involving the First Isomorphism Theorem but I don't know how to use it with a direct product. I've checked whether the groups are cyclic and also tried to just find functions $f:\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z\to(\Bbb Z/15\Bbb Z)^{\times}$ but that didn't get me anywhere. If possible, a hint would help.

Comment: How many elements are there in $(\Bbb Z/15\Bbb Z)^\times$? Use this together with the fundamental theorem of finite abelian groups.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We always have
$$
(\Bbb Z/pq\Bbb Z)^{\times}\cong (\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^{\times}\times (\Bbb Z/q\Bbb Z)^{\times},
$$
for primes $p$ and $q$ by the CRT (Chinese Remainder Theorem).

Furthermore we have $(\Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z)^{\times}\cong \Bbb Z/(p-1)\Bbb Z$.

References:

[$\mathbb Z_{mn}$ isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_m\times\mathbb Z_n$ whenever $m$ and $n$ are coprime](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/795919/mathbb-z-mn-isomorphic-to-mathbb-z-m-times-mathbb-z-n-whenever-m-and)

[Is my proof that $U_{pq}$ is not cyclic if $p$ and $q$ are distinct odd primes correct?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354559/is-my-proof-that-u-pq-is-not-cyclic-if-p-and-q-are-distinct-odd-primes-c)