# A direct product of multiplicative groups $\mathbb Z^*(p)$ and $\mathbb Z^*(q)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

This is an exercise 3, chapter 8 from Stein's Fourier Analysis.
In this chapter, the author deals with finite abelian groups and Fourier analysis on them. The problem is the following:
Let $p$ and $q$ be relatively prime. Prove that $\mathbb Z^*(p) \times\mathbb Z^*(q)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^*(pq)$. (Here $\mathbb Z^*$ means the multiplicative group.)

I know that for additive groups,  $\mathbb Z(a) \times\mathbb Z(b)$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z(ab)$ if $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime. Indeed, we can make an isomorphism, $$\phi:(1,1)\mapsto 1$$
But for multiplicative groups I don't know how to make an isomorphism between them. For example, $\mathbb Z^*(5)=\{1,2,3,4\}$ and   $\mathbb Z^*(7)=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$. Here how can we define an isomorphism mapping some element from $\mathbb Z^*(7)$ $\times\mathbb Z^*(5)$ to  $33\in\mathbb Z^*(35)$?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/354559/is-my-proof-that-u-pq-is-not-cyclic-if-p-and-q-are-distinct-odd-primes-c). There is an induced isomorphism for the unit groups of these rings.

Comment: The Chinese remainder theorem is an isomorphism of rings; in particular, it is an isomorphism of the additive groups, and it also induces an isomorphism of these multiplicative groups.

Comment: Thank you I haven't studied ring theory yet. I will search up related things.

Comment: In the duplicate, one answer uses ring theory, but the other one not. So you could read the second answer there.